# 404 not found error setting up Passport in Express 4

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I am really having troubles getting `passport` to work in my Node.js application. I tried reordering my requirements in my `app.js` but I still can't get it to work. This is the error I'm getting:

```
Not Found

404

Error: Not Found
    at /home/salma/Desktop/my-project/app.js:56:13
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/salma/Desktop/my-project/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/salma/Desktop/my-project/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
    at /home/salma/Desktop/my-project/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/salma/Desktop/my-project/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next (/home/salma/Desktop/my-project/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
    at /home/salma/Desktop/my-project/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:618:15
    at next (/home/salma/Desktop/my-project/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:256:14)
    at next (/home/salma/Desktop/my-project/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:121:14)
    at complete (/home/salma/Desktop/my-project/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:250:13)
    at /home/salma/Desktop/my-project/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:257:15
    at pass (/home/salma/Desktop/my-project/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:421:14)
    at Authenticator.transformAuthInfo (/home/salma/Desktop/my-project/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:443:5)
    at /home/salma/Desktop/my-project/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:254:22
    at /home/salma/Desktop/my-project/node_modules/passport/lib/http/request.js:60:7
    at pass (/home/salma/Desktop/my-project/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:267:43)
    at serialized (/home/salma/Desktop/my-project/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:276:7)
    at /home/salma/Desktop/my-project/config/passport.js:9:9
    at pass (/home/salma/Desktop/my-project/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:284:9)
    at Authenticator.serializeUser (/home/salma/Desktop/my-project/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:289:5)
    at IncomingMessage.req.login.req.logIn (/home/salma/Desktop/my-project/node_modules/passport/lib/http/request.js:50:29)
    at Strategy.strategy.success (/home/salma/Desktop/my-project/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:235:13)
```

Here's my code:

`app.js:`

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var flash    = require('connect-flash');
var passport = require('passport');
var session  = require('express-session');
var routes   = require('./routes/index');
var userRoutes   = require('./routes/user');
var adminRoutes   = require('./routes/admin');
var config = require('./config/index.js');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

var app = express();

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
var db = mongoose.connect(config.dbUrl, config.dbOpts);

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

var store = new MongoStore({
  mongooseConnection: db.connection
});

app.use(session({
  secret: config.sessionSecret,
  store: store,
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.use(flash());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
require('./config/passport')(passport);

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/', userRoutes);
app.use('/admin', adminRoutes);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

mongoose.connection.on('open', function(){
  mongoose.connection.db.listCollections(function(error, names) {
    if (error) {
      throw new Error(error);
    } else {
      names.map(function(name) {
        console.log('found collection %s', name);
      });
    }
  });
});

mongoose.connection.on('error', function(error){
  throw new Error(error);
});

module.exports = app;
```

and this is my log in route:

`routes/user.js:`

```
var express = require('express');
var User = require('../controllers/user');
var passport = require('passport');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.send('respond with a resource');
});

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local',
  { successFlash: 'Success!',
    failureFlash : 'Login failed' }));
```

and this is the file where I handle my `passport` authentication strategies:

`config/passport.js:`

```
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var User = require('../models/user').model;
var configAuth = require('./auth');

module.exports = function (passport) {
    passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });
    passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
        User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
            done(err, user);
        });
    });
    passport.use('local', new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField : 'email',
        passwordField : 'password',
        passReqToCallback : true
    },
    function(req, email, password, done) {
        User.findOne({ email :  email }, function(err, user) {
            if (err) return done(err);
            if (!user)
                return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'This email does not exist.'));
            if (!user.validPassword)
                return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! The password entered is incorrect.'));
            return done(null, user);
        });
    }));
    passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
        clientID: configAuth.facebookAuth.clientID,
        clientSecret: configAuth.facebookAuth.clientSecret,
        callbackURL: configAuth.facebookAuth.callbackURL,
        profileFields: ["emails", "displayName", "name"]
    }
}
```

I have tried other routes in the same route file to make sure the routes are seen by `app.js` and they work fine. Only this one doesn't. Can someone please tell what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: can you show your `user` model?

Comment: @ravishankar Thank you for your response. I realized the problem and will post the answer now :)

Comment: The problem that i told about in my answer, is it valid or not? Was it true, did you change to `user._id` in serializeUser`?

Comment: @ravishankar Tried it and it works too. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Error message that you are getting, i am guessing you are having an issue while `serializing` and `deserializing` the user.

It is a very simple mistake that you are doing.

while `serializing` the user, you are doing `user.id` which is `undefined`(i guess) That's why while `deserializing` it, the `function` is not getting the `ID`, and having problem finding it in the `user` collection.

It should be `user._id` instead of `user.id`. Change that and you should be good to go.

**Replace:**

```
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});
```

**With:**

```
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user._id);
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

The problem was in the route options `successFlash` and `failureFlash`. The `passport.authenticate()` function was expecting different options that must be used exactly that way otherwise they don't work. So when I replaced the options to match the documentation exactly as such:

```
app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
                                   failureRedirect: '/login',
                                   failureFlash: true })
);
```

or

```
 passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
            if (err) return res.status(500).send();
            if (!user) return res.status(400).json({error:info.message});
            req.logIn(user, function(err) {
                if (err) return next(err);
                return res.status(200).json(info.message);
            });
        })(req, res, next);
```

it worked. There are also other ways to call the function, they are listed in the documentation here:
http://passportjs.org/docs/authenticate

Comment: Solved my case. If you don't want to redirect, you have to supply a callback to app.post('/login', ...), otherwise it responds with 404 upon successful login.